# Ajax not getting response from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I really have no clue whats wrong with my code here. Response from php is not getting back to my ajax call.  Here is my code. JQuery

```
$(".theform").submit(function(e){
            var formData = {
                "name": $('#name').val(),
                "email": $('#email').val(),
                "phone": $('#phone').val(),
                "message": $('#message').val()
            }

            var sendMail = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'submit.php',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                encode: true
            });

            sendMail.done(function(output){
                if(output == "failed"){
                        console.log("failed");
                )
                        }
                });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

PHP

```
if($_POST){

$adminEmail = "";
$data = [];
$to = $adminEmail;
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['phone'];
$headers = "From: $email". "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = $_POST['message'];

$sendMail = mail($to, "Mail from $name", $message, $headers);


if($sendMail){
    $data = ["success"];
} else {
    $data = ["failed"];
   }
 }
print $data[0];
```

When i check the request, i see the response from the php but I can't seem to print it to screen or console in the ajax call. 
Please, what am i  doing wrong? By the way, it should return "failed" for now

Comment: Try printing response in console once and also Try `==` instead of `=` in your ajax success callback.

Comment: Add an error handler

Comment: If you're returning a simple string "failed" why do you specify `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: Thanks...It was actually  dataType: 'json' that was the issue